# Azure DevOps: Show Previous Attempts doesn’t work

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps for deployment activities (releases in yaml way)

From time to time I have to re-run stages if it fails,

The problem is that when I click on `Show Previous Attempts` nothing happens and I can't see Attempt #1
[image]

Is anybody facing the same? or any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, this issue has been confirmed as a bug and reported to the product group. Currently a fix for this issue has been prepared and the status is pending release.

You can keep track of this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1065522/show-preview-attempts-link-doesnt-work.html) in our Develop Community forum. We'll update you when it’s available.